# asp.net mvc-4: What should receive an ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC(-4).

I want to make an Ajax call from my website using jquery and fill in a div on the page using the returned html. Since it is only a div I do not need a full html page with header and full body and stuff.

What should be on the receiving side?

Should it be a normal view, a partial view, some special type of resource or handler or some other magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use this With Post and Get operaitons**

Script

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("SomeView")',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      data: { some_id: id},
      success: function(result) {
          $('#container').html(result);
      }
  });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SomeView(int some_id)
{
    ....
    return PartialView();
}
```

View

```
<div id="container">
    @Html.Partial("SomeViewPartial")
</div>
```

---

**OR you can use AjaxActionLink**

View

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller",
new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "container",
    OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
})
```

Script

```
function onSuccess(result) {
    alert(result.foo);
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SomeView(int some_id)
{
    return Json(new { foo = "bar" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

**Also** You can use Ajax.ActionLink to update only content page. with using this:

In `~/Views/ViewStart.cshtml:`

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Since it is only a div I do not need a full html page with header and full body and stuff

You want a [PartialView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can return a View which has the `Layout` property value set to null

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetUserInfo()
    {
      return View();
    }
}
```

and in `GetUserInfo.cshtml`

```
@{
  Layout=null;
}
<h2>This is the UserInfo View :)</h2>
```

And you can call it from any page by using jQuery ajax methods

```
$("#someDivId").load("@Url.Action("User","GetUserInfo")");
```

If you want the Same Action method to handle an Ajax call and a Normal GET request call, ( Return the partial view on Ajax, Return normal view on Normal Http GET request), You can use the `Request.IsAjax` property to determine that.

```
 public ActionResult GetUserInfo()
 {
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest)
    {
       return View("Partial/GetUserInfo.cshtml");
    }
    return View();  //returns the normal view.
 }
```

Assuming you have the Partial View (view with Layout set to null) is presetnt in `Views/`*YourControllerName*`/Partial` folder